# Tabbing not working....are arrow keys compliant?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, accessibility

Regarding accessibility, is using the arrow keys instead of tabbing through a form with multiple radio buttons considered compliant? Or does it have to allow for tabbing? I'm making a quiz and tab is only going to the first radio button and then directly to the submit button, skipping the other three options. But using the arrow keys it will cycle through all answer options for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using arrow keys is considered compliant with some help. Assigning `role=radiogroup` will let someone who is visually impaired know there are multiple options to choose.

Also, assigning `role="radio" aria-checked="false"` to each option will help screen readers know which is checked, and which is not.

Full code example:

```
<div role="radiogroup" aria-labelledby="gdesc1">
  <h3>Pizza Crust</h3>
  <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0">
    Regular crust 
  </div>
 <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1">
   Deep dish 
 </div>
 <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1">
   Thin crust 
 </div>
```

Checkout this [w3 example](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20160317/examples/radio/radio.html)

Comment: Before jumping into ARIA attributes, evaluate whether you can use native `<input type="radio">` first.  See the first rule of ARIA - https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#rule1

Answer (score 1):

Form controls for radio elements are limited to arrow keys only.

You can't actually 'tab' through radio controls.

To answer your question, arrow keys are compliant

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Many browsers let you tab through each individual radio button until you actually select one, then the browser makes the entire radio group one tab stop.  It's kind of weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the expected behaviour of radio buttons.  The group of radio buttons represents a single place in the tabbing order, and arrow keys provide the means of selection inside the radio group.

Using HTML radio inputs is greatly preferred, as web browsers will set this behaviour up automatically, so there's nothing special you need to do with JavaScript. See the [First Rule of ARIA Use](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#rule1).

If you're not using HTML radio inputs, follow the [Radio Group pattern from the WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#radiobutton), which describes the expected keyboard behaviours and ARIA semantics which you'll need to implement with JavaScript. Specimen implementations are also available there to study.